# broken pipe error with rails 3 while trying to upload data to AWS-S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload some static data to my aws s3 account.
I am using aws/s3 gem for this purpose.

I have a simple upload button on my webpage which hits the controller where it create the AWS connection and tries uploading data to AWS S3.

The connection to the AWS is successful, how-ever while trying to store data in S3, i get following error : Errno::EPIPE:Broken pipe" ...always.
I tried running the same piece of code from s3sh (S3 Shell) and i am able to execute all calls properly.

Am i missing something here?? its been quite some time now since i am facing this issue.

My config are : ruby 1.8, rails 3, mongrel, s3 bucket region us.

any help will be great.

Comment: I had this error while was working with apple push notifications workaround from http://gaveen.owain.org/2008/04/errnoepipe-broken-pipe-mysql-error-in.html solved problem

Answer (score 3):

I think the broken pipe error could mean a lot of things.  I was experiencing it just now and it was because the bucket name in my s3.yml configuration file didn't match the name of the bucket I created on Amazon (typo).

So for people running into this answer in the future, it could be something as silly and simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was with the file size.  S3 puts a limit of 5GB on single file uploads.  Chopping up the file into several 500MB files worked for me.

Comment: This was the problem for me as well. Chopping it into 4.5 GB files did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue uploading my application.css which had compiled file size > 1.1MB.  I set the fog region with:

```
config.fog_region = 'us-west-2'
```

and that seems to have fixed the issue for me...